# Custom domain for django tenants

Tags: django, python-3.x, saas

Can my tenant use their custom domain **xyz.com** instead of the public schema own subdomain like **tenant.mydomain.com**.

Assume I have a django tenant powered site with domain as **mydomain.com** & all tenants created have **t1.mydomain.com**, **t2.mydomain.com**, etc.

Can tenant t1 use **t1domain.com** instead of or alongside to **t1.mydomain.com**?
Same goes for t2, etc.

Comment: It depends on how you have deployed your app. At the very least you would have to allow those domains in your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting

Comment: Yes! thanks, that worked, but is there a way to add it dynamically from maybe the views to the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting. Considering the fact that django server will have to restart for the settings to be implemented.

Comment: You can allow all hosts by setting `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` but this is a potential security risk. The docs explain in more detail https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Comment: @IainShelvington thanks, here is what I did in the long run, `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*.DOMAIN.COM']` the subdomains created are linked to there actual domain by CNAME record.